# Waterbending: Warm Ice

Tags: science-based, physics, chemistry

Having in mind a scene from "Avatar: The Last Airbender" where Aang covers his body in a block of ice to float on water I'm wondering if it was possible to get H2O solid at arbitrary temperatures (e. g. 20°C) and how much power it would take to keep it from melting or even sublimating.

So I want to know how this might be achieved using bending in compliance to Real-World chemistry as well as using only Real-World possibilities.

Whereas my understanding of waterbending is the ability to magically control the movement of H2O-molecules.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for...  [Ice-Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice-nine)

Comment: It may be easier to maintain a temperature gradient such that they are surrounded by a layer of warm water, while keeping the exterior of the cube frozen for buoyancy.  Easier than changing physical properties or pressure or the like, anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can in fact make water be solid at room temperature. The only problem is, you need to compress it to pressures above 1GPa. A handy phase chart for reference:[image]

Comment: Being a person who can manipulate both air and water it could be very easy for him to increase the pressure and freeze it.

Comment: Okay thanks. But I can't find any way to enumerate the power necessary to keep up the pressure. I've read in [this forum](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-much-power-required-to-generate-a-particular-pressure.891246/) that power and pressure wouldn't have a "meaningful general relation". Is pressure even the right way to go here?

Comment: How can the temperature be regulated away from surrounding temperature?

Comment: Every time I see that chart I get to wondering about cookware made of ice.  At high enough pressure VII, X and XI are solids at cooking temperatures.

Comment: @Brian If the room temperature ice is stable, provide once it is formed under pressure it remains solid, then the ambient temperatures and pressures won't have any affect. Looks like ices VI, VII, X, and XI *might* do the trick. Of course, provided they're stable at lower pressures after formation.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The idea of cookware made of ice, well, ices VII, X, and XI, is amazing. You've certainly got me wondering too.

Comment: Accepting this now because there really is no proper correlation between pressure and energy ._. too bad